# Which religion to teach children when different religion parents?

Tags: parents, education

Salam,

If a man is Muslim and his wife Christian, it is allowed, but which religion should be taught to children ?

Is there example of sahaba, or famous religious person that was married to non-muslim person ?

Comment: https://islamqa.info/en/answers/130231/

Comment: Bro why would a Muslim ever want his child to go away from the true path. Obviously childrent should be taught Islam.